# I want to know how I should fill in the second parameter in order that I don't get str not callable error

Tags: python

Here's a sample of my code.

```
def send_text(mobile_phone, msg):

     customer_id = "..."
     api_key = "..."

     phone_number = mobile_phone
     message = msg
     message_type = "ARN"

     messaging = MessagingClient(customer_id, api_key)
     response = messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type)
     print(response, messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type))

send_text(input('Enter your phone number:')(?)).
```

I am not sure what to put in the second parameter. If I put a message in the second parameter then it give's me an error that says str isn't callable. If anyone can help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple parameters separated by comma

```
def send_text(mobile_phone, msg):

     customer_id = "..."
     api_key = "..."

     phone_number = mobile_phone
     message = msg
     message_type = "ARN"

     messaging = MessagingClient(customer_id, api_key)
     response = messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type)
     print(response, messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type))

send_text(input('Enter your phone number:'), input('Enter message:'))
```

Comment: Thank you I guess I thought I put a coma there

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put a coma before the (question mark)

```
def send_text(mobile_phone, msg):

    customer_id = "..."
    api_key = "..."

     phone_number = mobile_phone
     message = msg
     message_type = "ARN"

     messaging = MessagingClient(customer_id, api_key)
     response = messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type)
 print(response, messaging.message(phone_number, message, message_type))

send_text(input('Enter your phone number:'), (?))
```

And i guess the question mark is going to be

```
input('Enter your message:')
```

**Edit:**

You would simply say

```
send_text(input('Enter your phone number:'), "Hello how are you..")
```

Comment: I want to set a specific message in the second parameter like 'Hello how are you'

Comment: @bobsmith since your comment, i have made an edit. Check out.